# Github API Markdown - Anchor Links

Tags: node.js, github-api

I'm writing a NodeJS app for documentation using `.md` files, and I'm using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/github which uses this: https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/.

I'm passing our `.md` files through their API to return HTML, which I then cache for future use.

I'm having a issue with anchor links.

When I have this: `# Standard Parameters`, I get these results:

1.
Using `markdown.render()` with `mode: 'markdown'` and `markdown.renderRaw()` with either `mode: 'markdown'` or `mode: 'gfm'`:

```
<h2><a id="user-content-standard-parameters" class="anchor" href="#standard-parameters" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Standard Parameters</h2>
```

2.
Using `markdown.render()` and `mode: 'gfm'`:

```
<h2>Standard Parameters</h2>
```

So number 1 generates an anchor, and number 2 does not.

However, number 1 doesn't seem to even work. The `id` is `user-content-standard-parameters` (there is no `name` attribute) and the `href` is `#standard-parameters`.

Shouldn't the `id` value match the `href` value..? Like this:

```
id="standard-parameters" href="#standard-parameters"
```

or

```
id="user-content-standard-parameters" href="#user-content-standard-parameters"
```

or even

```
name="standard-parameters" href="#standard-parameters"
```

What am I missing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Github deals with this on their own website using a bit of JavaScript, so I've added something of my own to add a `name` attribute, removing the `user-content-` bit from the `id` value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[id^="user-content-"]').each(function(i, a){
        $(this).prop('name', a.id.replace('user-content-', ''));
    });
});
```